# Errors in setting up ROS tutorial workspace in "tf tutorials"

Tags: ros, tutorials, rosinstall, cturtle, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am learning ROS (ROS cturtle) from the tutorials. I got an error when setting up the ROS tutorial workspace in ["tf/tutorials"](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials).

It asked me to:

> **Create a file named
> ~/tutorials.rosinstall with the
> following content**:
>
> - other: local-name: workspace

> **To overlay on cturtle**:
>
> rosinstall ~/tutorials
> /opt/ros/cturtle
> ~/tutorials.rosinstall

I got confused with the term "workspace". I assume i gotta replace it with my working directory. I put it like

```
 - other: local-name: ~/tutorials.
```

Then I run

```
 rosinstall ~/tutorials /opt/ros/cturtle ~/tutorials.rosinstall
```

It prompts me an error:

```
rosinstall operating on /home/vincent/tutorials from specifications in rosinstall files  /home/vincent/tutorials/.rosinstall, /opt/ros/cturtle, /home/vincent/tutorials.rosinstall processing config_uri /opt/ros/cturtle ahhhhhhhh, yaml parse error: mapping values are not allowed here   in "/home/vincent/tutorials.rosinstall", line 3, column 19 Usage: rosinstall PATH [<options> ...] [URI]... 

rosinstall: error: None
```

Deleting the space between "local-name" and "~/tutorials" in that command-line solved this error. But got another error:

```
rosinstall operating on /home/vincent/tutorials from specifications in rosinstall files  /home/vincent/tutorials/.rosinstall, /opt/ros/cturtle, /home/vincent/tutorials.rosinstall
processing config_uri /opt/ros/cturtle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 461, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1194, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in <module>
    sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 506, in rosinstall_main
    result = insert_source_yaml(source_yaml, a, observed_paths, aggregate_source_yaml)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 386, in insert_source_yaml
    path = element[k]['local-name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

And I also tried replacing "workspace" with "/opt/ros/cturtle/stack" or "/opt/ros/cturtle/ros" or "/opt/ros/cturtle". They gave basically the same errors.

Can someone help me out? Probably obvious to everyone else, please excuse my dumbness.-_-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9415/errors-in-setting-up-ros-tutorial-workspace-in-%22tf-tutorials%22/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed that was bad syntax.  I've updated the tutorial to correctly read

```
- other: { local-name: workspace }
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-03-14**:
Thanks a lot, that's clear to me now~ But here comes another problem..It would be great if you could take time look at the question below... Thank you in advance~

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-14**:
The rosinstall file designates the path "workspace" inside ~/tutorials to be in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  You can change it to be whatever you want, it is a relative path from where rosinstall is pointed.

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-03-14**:
So I should type exactly the same code without replacing "workspace" with some directory path? I tried that and it worked fine, just want to make sure 'cause I don't quite understand this part.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some new thoughts here: I'm guessing in the tutorial the "ros_pkg_tutorials" just means some working directory. I can use another name as I want. For instance, I create the folder ~/tutorials/workspace and append that to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Then I'll cd to that folder and create the "learning_tf" package. Is it correct?

This is what you should do. Use the path created before and execute roscreate-pkg there.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-03-15**:
Cool, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well there is ros-cturtle-ros-tutorials as a deb package and there is http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros_pkg_tutorials.
IIRC you don't need that stack though. So you can use any directory in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-03-16**:
Thank you for reminding me. I checked that link before, it was listed as a ROS stack. But at that time I didn't know how to download that... Actually i'm totally a newbie to the linux world:-) And I am thinking maybe u want to remove the '.' at the end of the link you provided.